# AngularJS 2 dependency injection into sub-child components

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular

I am trying to make a card component similar to one in angular material. Everything is working perfectly except I am having some trouble getting the [title] dependency injection on each card to work.

Here is my code:

TitleDirective

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[title]'
})

export class TitleDirective {
    private _defaultTitle = '';

    @Input('title') title: string;

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        console.log('hhh');
        console.log(this.title);
    }
}
```

CardItemComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { TitleDirective } from '../title.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'card-item',
    templateUrl: 'app/directive/cards/card-item.component.html',
    directives: [
        TitleDirective
    ]
})

export class CardItemComponent { }
```

HTML page

```
<mc-cards>
    <mc-card>
        <mc-card-header>
            <mc-button>LEFT</mc-button>
            <span flex></span>
            <h1>Title 1</h1>
            <span flex></span>
            <mc-button>RIGHT</mc-button>
        </mc-card-header>
        <mc-card-body>
            <mc-card-item [title]="Hello">
                    <p>
                        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

                        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
                    </p>
            </mc-card-item>
        </mc-card-body>
    </mc-card>
</mc-cards>
```

I want each card-item to be able to set the title for the tab/card in the

Comment: What are you getting now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
[title]="'Hello'"
or
title="Hello"
```

Comment: @matt2405 If that answers your question please accept it to indicate your problem is solved (white checkmark below the up/down-vote buttons).